# Ran out of envelopes in randomized control trial

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

We are conducting a randomized control trial (RCT) comparing treatment vs. control from 4 sites (A-D). We have planned for 100 patients from each site. 100 envelopes of treatment assignment (intervention or control) were prepared for each of the sites using simple randomization lists (400 envelopes in total). However, it looks like we might not obtain a sample size of 100 from site D and were therefore thinking of increasing the sample size from site A to compensate. However, we do not have enough envelopes; only 100 envelopes were prepared per site (I guess this was a poor decision and we should have prepared a few more envelopes per site to be on the safe side). Let's say we want to add an extra 30 patients from site A. Can we use envelopes already prepared for site D for the treatment assignment? Or do we need to prepare a new additional set of 30 envelopes with treatment allocation for site A?

Comment: There are a number of assumptions here that are questionable but not outright statistical violations. Why overrecruit at site A? Because they enroll gangbusters? Overrecruiting at a single site reduces the statistical validity of a multicenter trial - adding to the issue of losing 30 at D. Also, why should you re-use the envelopes when the consideration is to reduce cost? Just re-issue envelopes for overrecruitment.

Answer (score 0):

Preserving the integrity of the randomisation procedure in an RCT is essential to guaranteeing the validity of the research findings. It is generally not advisable to use the envelopes from site D for site A for a number of reasons:

First, statistical power estimates that take into consideration expected effect sizes and variability within each site are typically used to establish the sample size at each location. Altering envelopes between locations may have an impact on the study's power and statistical assumptions.

Second, to account for site-specific features, the randomisation lists were created especially for each site. Since the randomisation sequence at site D might not be suitable for participants at site A, moving envelopes between sites could introduce bias.

Third, in a multicenter trial, sites may differ in terms of patient demographics and features. To guarantee that each treatment group is balanced with regard to these attributes within each site, it is crucial that the randomisation be stratified by site.

Finally, the institutional review board (IRB) or ethics committee normally has to give its approval before any major modifications to the study protocol, such as adjustments to the randomisation procedure, can be made. It's possible that using envelopes from a different location does not follow the originally approved methodology.

In light of these, it would be more suitable to construct a fresh set of thirty envelopes for site A.. This would guarantee that the additional patients are randomised in a way that is consistent with the original trial design and that the randomisation procedure is maintained. The actions you should do are as follows:

Therefore, I would advise making fresh envelopes and submitting a revised study protocol to the IRB (or ethics committee) with a description of the modifications, including the rationale for the larger sample size at site A and the new randomisation envelope technique. Then document the rationale for the change and the steps taken to maintain the integrity of the randomisation process, and finally, amend the statistical analysis plan to account for the changes in the sample size distribution across sites. This may involve adjusting for site effects in the analysis if there is a risk that the imbalance could introduce bias.